# Error Correction model and vector error correction model and their error correction terms

Tags: cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, variable, eviews, ecm

(1) What is the difference between these two ina bivariate variable? I know that VECM caters to more than one cointegrating vectors but equation wise what is difference between these two? Both uses difference of the dependent and independent variable itself and their lags plus the error correction term.

(2)Also when i model both using the x variable as dependent, the ect is significant but if i use y variable as the dependent, the ect is not significant. What does it mean?

Comment: By ECM, are you referring to the Engle-Granger approach? If yes, then VECM is theoretically much different from it because it considers all variables to be endogenous. In the Engle-Granger approach, we have to decide on a dependent variable and the independent variable is assumed to be weakly exogenous. If it's not exogenous, we may have a problem. If you are not referring to the Engle-Granger approach, please elaborate on how you estimated the ECM.

Comment: Yes. I used the two step engle-granger approach to build my ECM which is the d(x) c d(y) resid(-1) in eviews. It gave me satisfying results like significant and negative ect. However, when i used d(y) c d(x) resid2(-1) on my work, which is the exchanged dept and indep variables, it gave me non significant results. What exactly does it mean? Aren't they cointegrated and should be moving the same way?

Comment: I also tried using both x and y variable as the dependent in vecm and both gave me different results. When I used y variable coint eq (ceq) of y is significant but ceq of x is not. When i used x as the dependent variable, ceq of x is significant but ceq of y is not. What does it mean?

Comment: You cannot have dependent or independent variables in VECM, they are all treated as endogenous. There must be a mistake. I think you mean that the adjustment parameter of one equation of VECM is significant and the one in the other equation is insignificant. Did you check for Cointegration using Johansen Test? It's possible that there is no cointegration. It could also mean that one variable is leading and the other one is following and adjusting to it. Are the signs of adjustment parameters correct? there could be a lot of things going on.

Comment: Yes. The adjustment for x is significant but the adjustment for y is not. I used VAR and AIC to get the optimal lag length then proceeded to Johansen. It gave me satisfying and realistic results but then the vecm is giving me an insignifcant ect for the y equation but the sign is negative.